# Chrome suddenly crashing just after starting

Tags: google-chrome

Having used Chrome for years, it suddenly started failing to open. It gets as far as the opening screen with the Restore? box showing. Whatever I do after a few seconds it shuts down. No error message. I have removed and reinstalled a couple of times without success.

So I ran it in Terminal and get this:

```
[15881:15925:0521/085530.794880:ERROR:login_database.cc(641)] Password store database is too new, kCurrentVersionNumber=28, GetCompatibleVersionNumber=29
[15881:15925:0521/085530.795041:ERROR:password_store_default.cc(39)] Could not create/open login database.
[15916:15916:0521/085530.907906:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[15881:15909:0521/085531.061833:ERROR:login_database.cc(641)] Password store database is too new, kCurrentVersionNumber=28, GetCompatibleVersionNumber=29
[15881:15909:0521/085531.061921:ERROR:password_store_default.cc(39)] Could not create/open login database.
--2021-05-21 08:55:31--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 142.250.187.206, 2a00:1450:4009:81f::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|142.250.187.206|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

Crash dump id: 392a58148f3f9f5d

     0K                                     --2021-05-21 08:55:32--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 142.250.187.206, 2a00:1450:4009:81f::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|142.250.187.206|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

     0K
 Crash dump id:  aa4059a5adb3a524 
                                            Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I can't understand what has changed since yesterday. I did install Guayadeque, but can't see how that would affect it.

Comment: This happened to me a few days ago, when I was running Fedora 35 (on a machine that dual boots Win 10). I reinstalled Fe35. Happened again. I installed Ubuntu 20.04. After Audacity caused my system to run out of memory, I had to do a hard reboot. Chrome crashed yet again!  

I have two accounts on Google. Every time this problem occurs, (whether on Fedora or Ubuntu), when I try to log into my *main* account, Chrome crashes. It runs fine when I log into my #2 account, but my bookmarks are all on the main account.  

Mountain View, we have a problem.

Comment: `login_database.cc .. Password store database is too new, kCurrentVersionNumber=28, GetCompatibleVersionNumber=29` suggests that you upgraded to newer version and then downgraded to older version with the result that your Chrome profile data is no longer compatible with the older version. Most software is only forward compatible and downgrading may require restoring the profile (`~/.config/google-chrome`) from backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this command :

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
```

Though let me tell you that this will reset all your bookmarks, history. This is kinda like reinstalling chrome. If you had backedup your history into your email id then you can back it up easily after doing this command.

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the trick!

Comment: I did this, even still happening.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to start from scratch try deleting just the lock file:

rm ~/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

None of your advises worked for me regardless because I have come to find out that this is more of a technical issue on my standpoint of this error.

This error has been occurring with my Chrome since a long time now and I suppose it’s got to be because I have a very old PC that exists since 2009. The Chrome works perfectly for some months or an year or so then just suddenly starts having frequent crashes and corrupts the Operating System.

From the logs of the Chrome when running it via Terminal, we see that this issue is more of a hardware issue linked to the Graphics Processing Unit. With an old computer like the one I have, I don’t think it’s possible to fix such issue if there’s no latest drivers for it (If the issue is software related) but since I mostly suspect that it could be hardware related (Because of the fan speeding really fast without any cause) and the Terminal Logs for my PC indicating the issue being with the GPU, I’m sure there should be a replacement part for an absolute system.

Nonetheless, since I don’t want to proceed with replacement parts, it’s best to stick with one of the following options:

1. Reduce Hard Disk Drive Space (This helps maximize capacity of the Hard Disk Drive with Free Space so it doesn’t corrupt the File System). Having too much Hard Disk Drive Space results to the File System being congested on Linux. This way it’ll require you to perform fsck after every reboot or every time the file system gets corrupted because of the Chrome.
2. Use a Virtual Machine. Using a Virtual Machine helps contain everything within the Virtual Machine itself instead of having to run it on your local machine.
3. Reinstall the entire Operating System as a whole. This has happened to me several times when I have been using Linux Mint and I’m currently using Kali Linux. I’m sure this has to be much about the space of the Hard Disk, so be sure to contain the HDD Space. Reinstalling the whole OS as a whole fixed the problem when I had similar problems on Linux Mint (Although with the Mint Version, the File System Corruption was worse till it locked the entire system and couldn’t even get root privileges. It was like the entire OS was locked and inaccessible. With Kali Linux, the issue is similar in a way that once you lock your PC, you can never log back in and it’ll only give you an authentication error till you restart the system and run fsck from busybox through the grub bootloader);

I thought switching to Kali would fix the issue because it’s been long now that I have used Kali Linux and I haven’t encountered the issue till recently this December when it started again, every time I open Chrome, it crashes then after a while, corrupts the FileSystem. This made me understand that this is more of a storage issue because the more storage the computer used, the more the Linux OS detected the File System Corruption whenever I opened Chrome. Be sure to reduce apps that are unnecessary as well. With Kali Linux, the issue is only happening with Google Chrome. With Linux Mint, the issue has been happening throughout core functions of the Operating System (File Manager and more).

4. Try updating Chrome. Sometimes the issue could be caused because the Chrome hasn’t been updated since a long time. Linux doesn’t have an automatic update functionality so be sure to upgrade and run updates regularly.

Error Log from Chrome on Terminal:

```
    ┌──(brotheralameen㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ google-chrome                                          
[6275:6275:0101/155528.714761:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[6229:6229:0101/155530.226467:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
[6313:6313:0101/155530.420887:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[6353:10:0101/155531.274493:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[6345:10:0101/155531.275140:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[6306:8:0101/155531.294719:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[6435:6435:0101/155531.585762:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(402)] [.WebGL-0x5000088e200]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels
[6435:6435:0101/155531.839730:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(402)] [.WebGL-0x50000330700]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels
[6435:6435:0101/155531.972547:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(402)] [.WebGL-0x5000088e200]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels
[6435:6435:0101/155532.116371:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(402)] [.WebGL-0x50000330700]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels (this message will no longer repeat)
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
[6229:6257:0101/155546.194631:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(471)] ConnectionHandler failed with net error: -2
[0101/155553.785244:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[6276:6282:0101/155554.010309:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -3
[6276:6282:0101/155554.010656:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -3
zsh: bus error  google-chrome
```

I'm running Kali Linux based in Debian on a MacBook Pro 9" (2009) model.